# What does the number in the upper right of Grimoire cards mean?

Tags: destiny

Grimoire cards have a number next to what looks like an icon of stacked cards in their upper right corner. For me, anyway, this number is usually "0". Anyone know what this is supposed to signify?

Comment: I believe it either represents the amount of cards you have collected in this category *or* how many 'doubles' of this card you have. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the score that the card contributes to your Grimoire score (the same stack of cards symbol can be found under your characters emblem bar with a number). Some cards start at 0 and have points you can earn. You'll know you can earn points if when you see the card on the Bungie site it has a little chart looking button. Clicking on that will show you the different things you need to accomplish to earn more points with that card.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, this is the score the cards is worth. Many cards don't have score, because they are not "hard enough to get".

[Here](http://destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Grimoire_Cards), you can see a good overview of the Grimoire Cards, where it also states:
"*Grimoire Cards are collectible cards you unlock by reaching certain milestones in the game. Each Grimoire Card has Grimoire Points, which add to your overall Grimoire Score. Each Cards has a description on the back that details a piece of lore in the Destiny Universe. The cards will play a big part in unraveling the mysterious of Destiny as the player progress through the game.
Players can check the Grimoire Cards they have collected and their Grimoire Score on their profiles on Bungie website.*"

This is Bungie's system of keeping track of the experienced players. The higher the Grimoire Score, the more the player have played the game.